# OCR pdf converted files

Tags: windows-7

what is the procedure to copy the character in ocr converted PDF files.?
in some files of some grafic to ocr converted or image to pdf converted it is not able to copy or edit the character,please help me..

Comment: Have you tried selecting what you need.  Hitting ctrl+c then placing your cursor where you need it to go and hitting ctrl+v?

Answer (score 0):

Some PDF software cheats it inserts an image of the text instead of the text.  When this happens the text is unselectable and will not be editable.  These need to be OCR again, maybe with different software.  I have had excellent luck with "Omnipage pro"